# Invalid initializer member declaration error reading out XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have 2 classes:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public PersonDetail personDetails { get; set; }        
    }

    public class PersonDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
    }
```

When I want to read out the persons from the xml file I get this error "Invalid initializer member declaration":

```
 foreach (var item in xmlFile.Descendants("person"))
            {
                if (item.Element("id") != null)
                {
                    testList.Add(new Person()
                    {
                        **personDetails.Id** = item.Element("id").Value,
                        **personDetails.Name** = item.Element("name").Value,
                        **personDetails.Function** = item.Element("function").Value
                    });
                }
            }
```

I can't reach "id", "name" and "function" via "personDetails".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `PersonDetail`:

```
 testList.Add(new Person()
                {
                    personDetails = new PersonDetail 
                                        { 
                                           Id =  item.Element("id").Value,
                                           ...
                                        }
                });
```

Comment: Indeed that works, but when I read the xml out of the file I get this: object reference not set to an instance of a object'‏